# Google Maps API v3 repeats markers on custom map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, word-wrap, repeat

I have this problem for a while now, I have searched the web for answers, but I could not find a good answer related to my problem.

[image: screenshot of my problem]

You can see that I render my own set of tiles. The problem is that the markers are repeated horizontally, because of the wrapped map. I can't use the zoom in trick to avoid this problem, because the map has to be dynamic so it supports multiple resolutions.

I hope someone knows how to deal with this problem! I would really appreciate it.

I use Google Maps API v3.

**EDIT**

Here is another screenshot:

[image: another screenshot]

Comment: I would also like to know how to prevent this problem, as I do not use a horizontally repeating map in my custom map type.